# Facebook Audience Network NullPointerException on Android

Tags: android, facebook-audience-network

After implementing Facebook Audience Network, I'm seeing a lot of these errors being logged on play console and firebase.

I could never replicate it on my tests, but it is affecting a lot of my users and it's having a negative impact on my reviews.

I just wanted to know if anyone knows how to fix it before I remove this integration.

Here's the details:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2338)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2390)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1321)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:110)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5292)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:828)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:644)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.n.setUpContent (n.java)
  at com.facebook.ads.internal.view.n.a (n.java)
  at com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity.onCreate (AudienceNetworkActivity.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5287)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1088)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2302)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2390)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1321)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:110)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5292)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:828)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:644)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

Any way to catch this exception and prevent the app from closing?